# UTL_FILE.FGETATTR returns 0 for the block size

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle19c, utl-file

When I use UTL_FILE.FGETATTR, the block size returns 0 each time. I can get file length etc, but block size returns 0. What can be the reason for that and how can I solve this?
OS : Windows 10
DB : 19c

```
DECLARE
    v_fexists       BOOLEAN;
    v_file_length   NUMBER;
    v_block_size    BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.FGETATTR ('TEST_DIR','temp file.txt',v_fexists,v_file_length,v_block_size);
    IF v_fexists THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The file exists');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Its length is     :'||v_file_length);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Its block size is :'||v_block_size);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The file does not exist!');
    END IF;
END;
```

---

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The file exists
Its length is     :2794
Its block size is :0
```

Comment: can you provide an example ? because if the file exists, it should return the block size

Comment: I believe it is something related with Windows. Because I did the same test on Linux and it works without issues ( same database version )

Comment: Thank you Roberto. I think the same. So I made checkdisk etc but did not change.

Comment: did you try in another directory ? Perhaps the problem is windows 10 , which is not a windows server os version. I cannot test on windows on my side :(

Comment: I tried but it was also under the C drive. But my pc doesn't have any other drives

Comment: I think this is still expected on WIndows; see Doc ID 274466.1 on My Oracle Support. It only refers to 9i/10g but can't see that it's likely to have changed. (Seems like a documentation bug if that's the case, though...)

Comment: @AlexPoole , nice catch. Indeed that is the reason ;) I just check with one guy from support and the document applies to each Oracle version, even though it says only 9i/10g.

Comment: @oramas , you won't get the blocksize in Windows. It is not possible as the windows subroutine does not exist, at least the same way it does on Linux/Unix

Comment: I reproduced on an NTFS and exFAT file system, but the question is - why do you need it?

Comment: I was just worried if I did any mistake or my disk has problems. So in this case, does this mean that it doesn't work on Windows machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just post the answer that everybody is aware and you can mark the question as answered. It is more or less a recollection of everything we've been talking about on the comments section.

> On Windows platforms, UTL_FILE.FGETATTR procedure returns 0 instead of
> the correct block size even if the file exists. Windows platform does not provide any system sub-routine to obtain the filesystem I/O block size, as a result it returns 0, which is the expected behaviour.

Although it is predicted and documented for 9i/10g, the problem is reproducible on 12c, 18c and 19c as well.

[Link to Support Note](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=654013136255051&id=274466.1&_adf.ctrl-state=mhb00szxd_52)